# Bootstrap desktop fonts not matched on mobile

Tags: fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made a site with bootstrap - first impressions are very good!

I'm set some custom fonts for headings etc., but they're not reflected in the mobile site.

Any advice on what I need to add?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to debug without some code.  Can you give an example in bootply.com?  I could guess that you used a font installed on your computer... maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the font you are using is installed on not just the computer you are developing on but also the mobile device you are testing on. Remember different devices have different fonts installed.

One way of getting around this issue is using a service like [Google Web Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) where it will download the font to the user's device to be rendered on a webpage.